# How can I re-run the parent route code when I'm switching between the nested children routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Take a look at my protected route for unauthenticated pages:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Route, Outlet, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Login, SignUp } from '../pages'
import useVerifyToken from '../hooks/useVerifyToken'

const InauthenticatedRoutes = () => {

    const isAuth = useVerifyToken()

    return !isAuth ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/"/>
}

const routes = [
    <Route key="3234" path='/' element={<InauthenticatedRoutes />}>
        <Route key="6757" path='login' element={<Login />}/>
        <Route key="67567" path='signup' element={<SignUp />}/>
    </Route>
]

export default routes
```

The reason this file exported an array is because this will later be iterated inside the `Routes` element

the `useVerifyToken` is something like this

```
function useVerifyToken() {
  const jwt = localStorage.getItem('access')

  let data = 0

  useEffect(() => {

    ....verifying token

  }, [window.location.href])

  return !data ? 0 : 1;
}
```

As you can see inside the `useVerifyToken` hook there's a `useEffect` that has a `window.location.href` as a dependency this is because I want this hook to verify the token every time the user switch in between pages. But the problem here it's that if I went from the route `Login` to `Signup` which is nested under the same parent, the `useVerifyToken` wouldn't be triggered. Personally I can't really find any work around without radically changing the route structure.

My question

How do I trigger the `useVerifyToken` to run even if I have to access a route under the same parent route? if not then what kind of work around would you recommend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a bit of a rewrite of the `useVerifyToken` to have a loading state and the `isAuth` state. Return both values from the hook such that you can conditionally render some alternative UI while the token is being verified. Use the `useLocation` hook to access the `location.pathname` value to be used as a `useEffect` hook dependency. When the `pathname` changes the effect callback will run.

Example:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const useVerifyToken = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = React.useState();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const verifyToken = async () => {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('access');
      setIsLoading(true);
      try {
        ....verifying token
        setIsAuth(/* validation result, true|false */);
      } catch(error) {
        // handle error, log, set any error state, etc...
        setIsAuth(false);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };
    
    verifyToken();
  }, [pathname])

  return { isAuth, isLoading };
};
```

Update `InauthenticatedRoutes` to use both states returned from the hook:

```
const InauthenticatedRoutes = () => {
  const { isAuth, isLoading } = useVerifyToken();

  if (isLoading) {
    return null; // <-- or loading indicator, spinner, etc...
  }

  return !isAuth ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/" replace />;
}
```

Now just render the routes normally, no need for them to be in any array really.

```
<Routes>
  ...
  <Route element={<InauthenticatedRoutes />}>
    <Route path='login' element={<Login />} />
    <Route path='signup' element={<SignUp />} />
    ... other anonymous routes
  </Route>
  ...
</Routes>
```